# Ansible fortigate: "msg": AnsiballZ_ping.py:501-Permission Denied

Tags: ansible, fortigate

Today, I wanted to test Ansible to manage Fortigate, so, I set up a simulation environment.
when I echo `ansible fg -m ping`, I get an error msg, like this

> ```
> 192.168.18.150 | FAILED! => {
>     "msg": "failed to transfer file to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-46555w_4g4b_n/tmpdfc1l7yc ansible-test #/AnsiballZ_ping.py:\n\n501-Permission Denied\n"
> }
> ```

I did enable scp in Fortigate

```
config system global
  set admin-scp enable
```

And I already had `scp_if_ssh=True` in the `[ssh_connection]` section of *ansible.cfg*

Running the command with `-vvvv`, I get this

```
ansible 2.9.21
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
Skipping callback 'actionable', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'counter_enabled', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'debug', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'full_skip', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'json', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'null', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'selective', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'skippy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'stderr', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'unixy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'yaml', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<192.168.18.150> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.18.150> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607 192.168.18.150 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.18.150> (0, b'ansible-test # Unknown action 0\n\nansible-test # ', b'OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for \'final all\' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched \'final\'\r\ndebug2: match not found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: configuration requests final Match pass\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.18.150 is address\r\ndebug1: re-parsing configuration\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for \'final all\' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched \'final\'\r\ndebug2: match found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 192.168.18.150 [192.168.18.150] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9996 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 9ykfFlSYGl\r\ndebug1: no match: 9ykfFlSYGl\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to 192.168.18.150:22 as \'root\'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Nc7FkHufEKwgh9crfaEY29MT+TL6ViLrSveeqxKMZp4\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug1: Host \'192.168.18.150\' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks\r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss \r\ndebug2: pubkey_prepare: done\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup password\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled password\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: password\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 52\r\ndebug1: Enabling compression at level 6.\r\ndebug1: Authentication succeeded (password).\r\nAuthenticated to 192.168.18.150 ([192.168.18.150]:22).\r\ndebug1: setting up multiplex master socket\r\ndebug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607.T9XUgVl1r7oQVeCe\r\ndebug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 0: new [/root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607]\r\ndebug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 6\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY\r\ndebug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20\r\ndebug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process\r\ndebug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 47183\r\ndebug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: forking to background\r\ndebug1: Entering interactive session.\r\ndebug1: pledge: id\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds\r\ndebug1: multiplexing control connection\r\ndebug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]\r\ndebug3: channel_post_mux_listener: new mux channel 1 fd 7\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1: hello sent\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: cancel scheduled exit\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x00000001 len 4\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_hello: channel 1 slave version 4\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000004 len 4\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_alive_check: channel 1: alive check\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 47185\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000002 len 100\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel 1: request tty 0, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term "xterm-256color", cmd "/bin/sh -c \'echo ~ && sleep 0\'", env 1\r\ndebug3: mux_master_process_new_session: got fds stdin 8, stdout 9, stderr 10\r\ndebug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 2: new [client-session]\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel_new: 2 linked to control channel 1\r\ndebug2: channel 2: send open\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 90\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 80\r\ndebug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 91\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback start\r\ndebug2: client_session2_setup: id 2\r\ndebug1: Sending environment.\r\ndebug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending command: /bin/sh -c \'echo ~ && sleep 0\'\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request exec confirm 1\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug3: mux_session_confirm: sending success reply\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback done\r\ndebug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 99\r\ndebug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2\r\ndebug2: exec request accepted on channel 2\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 96\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd eof\r\ndebug2: channel 2: output open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 2: obuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_write (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 9 efd 10 [write])\r\ndebug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0\r\ndebug3: mux_exit_message: channel 2: exit message, exitval 0\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd eow\r\ndebug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 8 efd 10 [write])\r\ndebug2: channel 2: input open -> closed\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 97\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd close\r\ndebug3: channel 2: will not send data after close\r\ndebug2: channel 2: send close\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 97\r\ndebug2: channel 2: is dead\r\ndebug2: channel 2: gc: notify user\r\ndebug3: mux_master_session_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 2\r\ndebug2: channel 1: rcvd close\r\ndebug2: channel 1: output open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock 7 wfd 7 efd -1 [closed])\r\ndebug2: channel 1: input open -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 2: gc: user detached\r\ndebug2: channel 2: is dead\r\ndebug2: channel 2: garbage collecting\r\ndebug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3\r\ndebug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o1/16 e[closed]/0 fd 7/7/-1 sock 7 cc -1)\r\n  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/10 sock -1 cc -1)\r\n\r\ndebug2: channel 1: obuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock 7 wfd 7 efd -1 [closed])\r\ndebug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 1: is dead (local)\r\ndebug2: channel 1: gc: notify user\r\ndebug3: mux_master_control_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 1\r\ndebug2: channel 1: gc: user detached\r\ndebug2: channel 1: is dead (local)\r\ndebug2: channel 1: garbage collecting\r\ndebug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2\r\ndebug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o3/0 e[closed]/0 fd 7/7/-1 sock 7 cc -1)\r\n\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<192.168.18.150> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.18.150> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607 192.168.18.150 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ansible-test #/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo ansible-test #/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1621247104.1598728-47178-216424895417051 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1621247104.1598728-47178-216424895417051="` echo ansible-test #/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1621247104.1598728-47178-216424895417051 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.18.150> (0, b'ansible-test # Unknown action 0\n\nansible-test # ', b"OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match not found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: configuration requests final Match pass\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.18.150 is address\r\ndebug1: re-parsing configuration\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 47185\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n")
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<192.168.18.150> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-47171dn7wxth0/tmpbu4qybui TO ansible-test #/AnsiballZ_ping.py
<192.168.18.150> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 scp -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/db7eeee607 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-47171dn7wxth0/tmpbu4qybui '[192.168.18.150]:'"'"'ansible-test #/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"''
192.168.18.150 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "failed to transfer file to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-47171dn7wxth0/tmpbu4qybui ansible-test #/AnsiballZ_ping.py:\n\nExecuting: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.18.150, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t 'ansible-test #/AnsiballZ_ping.py'\nOpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match not found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: configuration requests final Match pass\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.18.150 is address\r\ndebug1: re-parsing configuration\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.18.150 originally 192.168.18.150\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 47185\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\n501-Permission Denied\ndebug2: Exiting on signal: Hangup\r\n"
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work on FortiGates since the ping module is not a regular ICMP ping. If you look up the docs of the ping module you can see that the remote-node requires Python.

From the docs:

> This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that
> requires Python on the remote-node.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html#synopsis